# Shorten/optimize an ExpandableListView

Tags: java, optimization, android

I have an expandable list view:

```
public class ExListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;

    private ExpandableListView exv;

    private String[] sportList;

    private final int AVAILABLE = 3;

    private String[][] childList = {
            { "Fifa Net Width", "Fifa Penalty Kick" },
            { "NBA Free Throw Line", "NBA 3pt Line" },
            { "Pitching Mound", "Base Distance" },
            { "Available in the Paid Version" },
            { "Available in the Paid Version" },
            { "Available in the Paid Version" },
            { "Available in the Paid Version" } };

    private InputValues iv;

    private int lastExpandedGroupPosition;

    public ExListViewAdapter(Context context, ExpandableListView e) {
        this.context = context;
        this.iv = (InputValues) context;
        this.sportList = iv.getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.sportsCategories);
        this.exv = e;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPos, final int childPos,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Button tv = new Button(context);
        tv.setText(childList[groupPos][childPos]);

        if (groupPos < AVAILABLE) {
            tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    iv.setPresetType(sportList[groupPos],
                            childList[groupPos][childPos]);
                }

            });
        } else {
            tv.setEnabled(false);
        }
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        if (groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition) {
            exv.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
        }

        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
        lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPos) {
        return childList[groupPos].length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return sportList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPos) {
        return groupPos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPos, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(sportList[groupPos]);
        tv.setPadding(55, 0, 0, 0);
        tv.setTextSize(25);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition,
            int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

I feel like parts of the code, like the childlist, can be replaced with something or fixed up. Does anyone know of a shorter/more efficient way to create an expandable list view?

**EDIT:**

Due to some people answering, I have decided to put up a more recent version of the code, with their corrections.

```
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends
        BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;

    private ExpandableListView expListView;

    private final int FREE_LIMIT = 3;

    private String[] sportList;

    private String[][] childList;

    private Input inp;

    private int lastExpandedGroupPosition;

    private Resources res;

    public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ExpandableListView expListView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.inp = (Input) context;
        this.res = inp.getResources();
        this.sportList = res.getStringArray(R.array.sportsCategories);
        this.childList = new String[sportList.length][10];
        populateChildList();
        this.expListView = expListView;
    }

    private void populateChildList() {
        for (int x = 0; x < sportList.length; x++) {
            childList[x] = Presets.getSportsPresets(sportList[x]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPos, final int childPos,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String CHILD = childList[groupPos][childPos];
        final Button BTN = new Button(context);
        final int BTN_BG_COLOR = res.getColor(R.color.steelblue);

        BTN.setText(CHILD);
        BTN.setBackgroundColor(BTN_BG_COLOR);
        BTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BTN.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.gray));
                inp.setPresetType(sportList[groupPos], CHILD);
                inp.mSlidingLayer.closeLayer(true);
                expListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
            }
        });

        if (groupPos > FREE_LIMIT - 1)
            BTN.setEnabled(false);
        return BTN;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        if (groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition)
            expListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
        lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPos) {
        return childList[groupPos].length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return sportList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPos) {
        return groupPos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPos, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tView = new TextView(context);
        tView.setText(sportList[groupPos]);
        tView.setPadding(60, 10, 20, 10);
        // tv.setBackgroundColor(iv.getResources().getColor(
        // R.color.steelgreen));
        tView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tView.setTextSize(30f);
        tView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

        return tView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition,
            int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Data Sources

You have three different sources of your data....

1. `sportList` is an array of the group values, and it is pulled from `R.array.sportsCategories`.
2. `private final int AVAILABLE = 3;` is a constant defined in the class.
3. `childList` is declared as an array in the class, but has extra data.

The reality is that `AVAILABLE` should be calculated from `sportList`, and the `childList` should be pulled from `R` as well.

### Naming Convention

> ```
> Button tv = new Button(context);
> ```

`tv` is a bad name, and it is because you copy/paste code from a `TextView` based method. In IDE's it is really easy to rename variables, even if the code is copy/pasted. There is no excuse ... ;-)

### Efficiency

Apart from the above, I can't see any significant inefficiencies that need to be rectified. This code is run very few times, and is a low priority for efficiency.

Comment: Thanks, I have done so and have posted a more updated code because that one was from 6 months ago. I renamed the button and have made the childlist to be pulled from resources in another class.

Answer (score 3):

Two minor notes:

1. I've found that abbreviation, like `ExListViewAdapter` and `exv` has two problems. First, it kills autocomplete 
   (if you type `Exp` and press Ctrl+Space in Eclipse it does not found `ExpandableListViewAdapter`). Second, readers/maintainers have to memorize them, they use valuable short-term memory slots. A longer name would avoid mental mapping. (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Avoid Mental Mapping*, p25)
2. `childList[groupPos][childPos]` is used twice in `getChildView`. It could have a local variable to remove duplication.

Comment: Thanks, I have done so and have posted a more updated code because that one was from 6 months ago. I made the local variable and change the ExListViewAdapter to ExpandableListViewAdapter